# How to make a basic ggplot2 time series graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I need to graph

```
sat -0.038685744            
sun -0.004397419            
mon -0.072163337            
tue 0.123328564         
wed 0.021875962         
thu 0.005030862         
fri 0.002869955
```

but the steps on r-graph-gallery are confusing, so can someone help me out with a simple graph that shows days of the week on the x axis in `ggplot2`?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? Is your data in R? Is it a data frame? Questions like this are difficult to answer and are often closed as "too broad" because you show *so little* that it's hard to know what you can do and what you can't do. If you're having trouble following an example from the R graph gallery, perhaps you should ask your question about that, showing your code and explaining where you get confused - then we can help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I convert your sample data into a dataframe (though next time you really should use `dput` to share your data):

```
df = read.table(text = "
            sat -0.038685744            
            sun -0.004397419            
            mon -0.072163337            
            tue 0.123328564         
            wed 0.021875962         
            thu 0.005030862         
            fri 0.002869955 ")
colnames(df) = c("day", "thing")
```

And here's how I convert the dataframe into a bar chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(day, thing)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 2):

Next time present data in reproducible manner, so that others do not retype it again.

```
# your data 
df <- tribble(
  ~week_day, ~value,
  "sat", -0.038685744,            
  "sun", -0.004397419,           
  "mon", -0.072163337,            
  "tue", 0.123328564,         
  "wed", 0.021875962,         
  "thu", 0.005030862,         
  "fri", 0.002869955 
)
df

ordered <- c("sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat")
df$week_day <- factor(df$week_day, levels = ordered)

ggplot(df, aes(x = week_day, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[code was adjusted based on Gregor's suggestions]

Comment: I ordered days so that they are in usual sequence, otherwise they will be alphabetically ordered (fri - first, wed - last). My reason was the following: week_day is a categorical variable and it did not allow to use geom_line(). That is why I first ordered categorical variable, then assigned each day a numeric equivalent (df$day) and applied scale_x_continuous to mask numeric values by categorical on the x-axis. group=1 solution will solve the problem without scale_x_continuous() as you've suggested - thank you for the suggestion! I will edit the code.

Comment: I put a reference that code was adjusted based on Gregor's suggestions. Thank you for the correction!